# composer psr-0 autoloader and symlinks

Tags: php, symlink, composer-php

I have a legacy application which I am slowly converting to composer, and am writing a new database layer for. This database layer is PSR-0 compatible. The application is split into back and front end, and I am writing common classes for the DB layer so it is more DRY.

In my composer.json for the front end project I have this:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "CompanyName": "_classes/"
        }
    }
```

where the CompanyName folder in _classes is in fact a symlink to the analogous folder in the back end project.

This causes the autoloading to fail.

It worked perfectly when it was

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "CompanyName": "../otherProject/_classes/"
        }
    }
```

but failed when put a symlink in this projects _classes folder.

I need the symlink to work because i do not want to hard code the other projects web folder name into composer.json, as I now have testing versions of both which have different folder names.

Comment: Shouldn't the database layer be a distinct library that is used twice? Then you wouldn't have autoloading problems, I am sure.

Comment: I am working within the constraints of the old system at the moment. Eventually it will be perfect, but one thing at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that my symbolic link was relative, which caused it not to work properly. I recreated the link using full paths:

```
ln -sf /web/otherProject/_classes/CompanyName /web/project/_classes/CompanyName
```

and now there is no problem.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you, you're the only one I found with my configuration, maybe you could help me :) I also created a symlink, but when I run `composer update -o` Composer don't understand the classes folder. Do you have an idea ? Please ..